# How to read different .env files depending on production or development mode?

Tags: webpack, vue.js, vue-cli

I am using Vue and webpack, with an environment variable that tells webpack to build for production or development.

**This is working:**

```
NODE_ENV=production webpack

console.log(process.env)
```

But, [this documentation explains](https://alligator.io/vuejs/working-with-environment-variables/) that you can use different `.env` files according to production or development mode, to change variables in your app.

**.env** file

```
VUE_APP_ROOT=http://localhost:8000/
VUE_APP_BASE_URL=http://localhost:8000/api/
```

**.env.prod** file

```
VUE_APP_ROOT=http://realaddress/
VUE_APP_BASE_URL=http://realaddress/api/
```

But I'm not clear on how these .env files get accessed? Apparently this works when you use `vue-cli`, but in my app this logs undefined:

```
console.log("environment variables")
console.log(process.env.VUE_APP_ROOT)
console.log(process.env.VUE_APP_BASE_URL)
```

How can I access different `.env` files depending on production mode, without `vue-cli` ?

Comment: As an alternative, you could use [switchenv](https://github.com/christiaanwesterbeek/switchenv). It's command line utility for quickly switching .env file from Keepass entries (content from the Notes field). I'm the author.

Comment: You can use https://github.com/hk-labs/dotenv-flow-webpack, it does just what you need.

Comment: FYI, the creators of dotenv [explicitly discourage](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv#should-i-have-multiple-env-files) creating several `.env` files, each for its own environment

Comment: OK, but how then do you change the variables depending on the mode?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you can use the [dotenv](https://github.com/mrsteele/dotenv-webpack) plugin.

```
// webpack.config.js
const Dotenv = require('dotenv-webpack');

module.exports = {
  ...
  plugins: [
    new Dotenv()
  ]
  ...
};
```

To load file based on environment, you can leverage `process.env.NODE_ENV`:

```
// webpack.config.js
const Dotenv = require('dotenv-webpack');
const env = process.env.NODE_ENV;

module.exports = {
  ...
  plugins: [
    new Dotenv({
      path: `./.env.${env === "production" ? "prd" : "dev"}`,
    })
  ]
  ...
};
```

You can see vue-cli doing a similar thing in this [repo](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/blob/dev/packages/%40vue/cli-service/lib/Service.js#L83-L111)

Comment: Thanks, this loads the `.env` file! But now I'm stuck at how to load the `.env.prod` file? It seems webpack always loads `.env`, even in production mode.

Comment: Thanks ! Just a little typo to fix here => path: `./.env.${env === "production" ? "prd" : "dev"}`,